# How to get an instanced Object from an incomplete class name?

Tags: java, constructor, classloader

world! I need to instantiate an Object from the name of its Class. I know that it is possible to do it, this way

```
MyObject myObject = null;
try {
    Constructor constructor = Class.forName( "fully.qualified.class.name"  ).getConstructor(); // Get the constructor without parameters
    myObject = (MyObject) constructor.newInstance();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The problem is that the name of my class is not fully qualified. Is there a way to get the complete name by only knowing the short name?

Comment: Would the class already be loaded? B/c then you can list all the loaded classes and compare against them... I have to ask though, why is this necessary? Maybe there is a better solution to a higher level problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MyObject myObject = null;
for (Package p : Package.getPackages()) {
    try {
        myObject = Class.forName(p.getName() + "." + className).newInstance();
        break;
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        // ignore
    } 
}
```

The `Package.getPackages()` call will give you every package known to the current classes ClassLoader *and its ancestors*.

Warning: this will be expensive because you are repeatedly throwing and catching exceptions.  It may be possible to speed it up by testing:

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().findResource(binaryClassName) != null
```

before calling `Class.forName(...)` or the equivalent.

Comment: Good, thank you! FYI, there's a missing `+ "."` between p.getName() and className.

Answer (score 1):

Try this repeatedly for a package search path. ;)

```
String[] packages = ...;
String className = ...;
MyObject myObject = null;
for(String p : packages)
  try {
    myObject = Class.forName(p + '.' + className).newInstance();
    break;
  } catch (Exception ignored) {
  }
```

Comment: This is likely the only way to do exactly as requested, although I would catch only the specific exception, i.e. ClassNotFoundEx or whatever.... you don't want to hide some other problem...

Comment: @Java Drinker, This is true, you could get side effects as well if a failing constructor has side effects. One of the downsides of using newInstance() this way is that it could throw CNFE as well. (Though fairly paranoid to worry about that) i.e. this newInstance() does NOT wrap checked exceptions.